# Calculating weekdays on Sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me about this sql case:
I want to add case if the calculation day of my script is in the weekdays Monday to Friday, what should I add to my script?

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.cid,
          a.SUBMIT_DATE,
          a.REQ_BY,
          a.MITRA,
          a.COSTUMER_TYPE,
          a.COSTUMER_NAME,
          a.ADDRESS,
          a.DESC,
          a.CREATED_DATE,
          a.TICKET_STATUS,
          CASE
              WHEN datediff(CURDATE(), A.SUBMIT_DATE) > 3 THEN 'OVER_SLA'
              ELSE 'CLEAR'
          END AS 'STATUS_SOLVE'
   FROM complaint a
   LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid)a
WHERE a.STATUS_SOLVE ='OVER_SLA'
  AND a.ticket_status='INPROGRESS'
```

Comment: WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) returns the day of week: 0 if today is Monday, 1 if Tuesday and so on, 6 for Sunday.

Comment: @Ramana changed to be : WHEN datediff(WEEKDAY(CURDATE()), A.SUBMIT_DATE) > 3 THEN 'OVER_SLA', but not show anything result just  showing : "Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.0010 sec )"

Comment: What is the requirement in terms of CURDATE(), SUBMIT_DATE and the day of week? Should the SUBMIT_DATE be a weekday or the CURDATE()?  Let us describe it in words so we can translate to SQL. Is the requirement in terms of the number of days between CURDATE() and SUBMIT_DATE?

Answer (score 0):

if date in integer form :

```
   SELECT DATENAME( dw, DATEFROMPARTS( @Year, @Month, @Day ) )
```

for string :

```
  SELECT DATENAME( dw, CONVERT( date, CONCAT( @Day, '/' , @Month, '/', @Year      ), 103 ) )
```